# calculate total number of particular element of a page after the page is fully loaded (there should be no specific load more button)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i have a webpage where user is selecting filter for particular web element and based on web element the number of transaction is displayed , now here is the thing , the total number of transactions are not displayed in single page  , there is "load more activity button" which user needs to click until all the pages are loaded or the button  is not displayed to get the total count of the transactions 
so once the all the pages are loaded , i want to count the transaction and validate

kindly help.

```
//activitybutton.isdisplayed = "load more activity" button
//click activity button 
//count total no of transaction

public void validateCategoryDisplayDetails() {

    filterbutton.click();
    airline.click();
    donebutton.click();

    while(activityButton.isDisplayed())
    {
        activityButton.click();
    }

    int countxpath = transactionday.size();

    //return countxpath;
    System.out.println(countxpath);
}
```

Comment: What is `transactionday`? Can you show how your elements are declared? Looks like probably with `@FindBy` annotations but whether or not you are using some framework makes a difference too.

Comment: yes i am using @FindBy annotations , do you need more details .kindly reply.

Comment: new code,first i am   counting the button on first page which will be 1,one button display every page ,it click the buttn nd new page loaded until the button wont be displayed  the screen,nw i m coming of the loop nd calculate total number of transactions and print count ,error message now stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

  int count= countactivitybutton.size();
  
  while (count>0)
  {       activityButton.click();
   count= countactivitybutton.size();
 }
   int countxpath = transactionday.size();
   System.out.println(countxpath);
  }
  }

Comment: `StaleElementReferenceException` is raised when you attempt to operate on a `WebElement` which refers to an object that is no longer part of the document. This is a strong indication that when you `activityButton.click()` that the entire page (or at least the important bits) are redrawn. You will have to fetch `activityButton` again via `driver.findElement`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `transactionday` was probably declared something like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath="xpath/matching/all/transactions")
List<WebElement> transactionday;
```

The moment you make a call to `PageFactory.initElements` each of the `@FindBy` annotated members are processed. Even the ones that are not annotated will attempt to be located according to their `name` attribute if they are of type `WebElement`. At this moment in time, not all of the transactions are loaded on the page, so this list ends up only containing those that exist at this point in time. While those `WebElement` objects in the list *may* continue to reflect the actual state of the object on the page, the xpath will not be automatically reevaluated to put more elements into the list.

Later, when you have ensured that all elements are loaded on the page, you need to locate the transactions again. Assuming you have a reference to your `WebDriver` called `driver`

```
int countxpath = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath/matching/all/transactions")).size()
```

If you were using a framework like SerenityBDD you might have been able to get away without explicitly re-evaluating the xpath, as that framework uses proxies to lazily evaluate instance members of `WebElement` types at the latest possible moment, rather than when the page object is initialized.

**Note:** If clicking on the button to load more results causes some or all of the page to be rendered all over again, you may need to fetch that button again via a call to `driver.findElement` after the page is re-rendered.